# no module named 'bs4' error when compiled

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This demonstrates how to log into a website. It is very fragile but
the goal is to demonstrate how to deal with forms, submit them, and
use a session to maintain cookies across page reads
this program assumes that you've done the research and you know what
fields you need to fill in.

```
import sys
import requests
import lxml
import getpass
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sys.path.append("../lib")

from agentsGalore import agentsGalore
from formHelper import formHelper
```

start a session
    session = requests.Session()
    ag = agentsGalore()

```
def openURL(url,cookie=None):
global session
global ag
headers = ag.makeHeader("MacFirefox58","default","default","langUS")
try:
    if cookie:
        r = session.get(url, cookies=cookie, headers=headers)
    else:
        r = session.get(url, headers=headers)
 except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(e)
    exit(1)

 return r
```

this function does a POST to the URL with the params in a hash
    def postURL(url,params):
    global ag
    global session
    headers = ag.makeHeader("MacFirefox58","default","default","langUS")
    try:
        r = session.post(url, data=params)
     except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
        print(e)
        exit(1)

```
return r
```

first, open the login page

```
url = 'https://my.wlc.edu/ICS/'

resp = openURL(url)
fh = formHelper(resp.text)
```

get a populated param structure.  You can call fh.analyzeInputs() to
see what all the input fields are.

```
params = fh.populateFormInputs(fh.getFormById('MAINFORM'))

userid   = getpass.getpass("enter your userid:",sys.stderr)
password = getpass.getpass("enter your password:",sys.stderr)

params['userName'] = userid
params['password'] = password

formurl = 'https://my.wlc.edu/ICS/'
res = postURL(formurl,params)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run:

```
apt-get install Python-bs4
```

or

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

or

```
easy_install beautifulsoup4
```

in the command line to install the package beautifulsoup4.

Comment: I'm on a school computer, so I don't have admin rights. I am currently in a virtual environment

Comment: @Ty'TeonnaFranklin Are you using virtualenv or a virtual machine？

Comment: Virtualenv sorry

Comment: @Ty'TeonnaFranklin try: source env_path/bin/activate to enter the virtual environment and then you can use pip to install packages in the virtualenv.